# Adding one more click event to tag jquery for Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

i need to write a click event for 'a' tag which has already another click event.

so latest event should run before the previously added event.

For Google Chrome Extension

Code :-

```
$(document).on("click","a",function(event){
alert('okay..');
});
```

Update :-

Current Issue :- when click the 'a tag' the web page event triggering first my event not running.
Requirement :- i creating a chrome extension for which i need to override websites onclick event of an 'a tag' (run my event first then only that webpage event should run).

Comment: Hi! Could you provide some code?

Comment: Hi Littm,  i updated the question

Comment: I don't see any code XD...